# How to minify sass-files via the Terminal?

Tags: terminal, sass, gulp-sass

How to minify sass-files via the Terminal? I installed Gulp locally inside my Project but now I need to minify my sass-file within my project via gulp inside the Terminal, but I don't know how (bloody noob...). Which certain commands are used for minimizing sass files inside the Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install gulp both locally and globally for gulp commands to work. As CSS is what would be delivered to the browsers, you would need a build pipeline to compile sass to CSS and then minify the same. [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) would do the CSS minification.

For further reading, [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-gulpy-workflow-sass/) is a nice blog.